# Calculate textpixel width with jQuery

Tags: jquery, width, tooltip

I want to add a simple tooltip to my menu. How do I calculate how many pixels the text in my 
tooltip has?

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Item 1 text">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Item 2  longer text" >Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" title="Item 3 text text text">Item 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
nav{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    background: grey;
}
ul{
    width: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
span{
    position:absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    background:black;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    border-bottom:none;
    display:none;
    color:white;
}
li:hover span{
    display:block;
}
a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px;

}​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav li').each(function(){
        $(this).append('<span>'+$(this).find('a').attr('title')+'</span>');
    });
    $('nav li span').each(function(){
        // var textwidth = ???? 
        // $('nav li span').css("left",-textwidth/2);
        // $('nav li span').css("width",textwidth);
    });
});
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/vxUTZ/1/
​

Comment: `$(this).text().length` Found by using brains

Comment: You are calculating how many characters there are, not the width of those characters

Comment: GJ sherlock, so you only have to ask for the css property textwidth, because it is different in every browser on every device....

Comment: @Bondye, completely unconstructive comments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).width();
```

Use the code above and you'll get the width of your span, but before you have to change the behaviour of the whitespaces in your span in your css-part:

```
span { white-space: nowrap; }
```

With this, there won't be a line break after every whitespace and the calculated width is the width of your text

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(this).width();
```

or you can also use

```
$(this).attr("width");
```

in your function.if you want to cal your text lenght then

```
$(this).text().length;
```

Comment: I need the width of the text if they where on one line, not the number of characters in the span

Comment: Then put $(this).text().width(); or $(this).attr("width")